# Clarity on Big-O

Tags: asymptotics

so I just had this question, I know that for example $g(n) = 100$, then $O\big(g(n)\big) = O(1)$. Let us take $a(n)$ as some function like $n\log n$, does this mean that $a(n)\in O\big(g(n)\big)$?

Comment: Your question is missing clarity.

Comment: Are you asking whether $n \log n \in O(100)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have $g(n) = 100$, in which case $g(n)$ is $O(1)$. You then define $a(n) = n\log n$ and ask if $a(n)$ is $O(g(n))=O(1)$.

The answer is no.

For $a(n)$ to be $O(1)$, it would have to be true that $n\log n$ was bounded by a constant from some point and onwards, but $n\log n$ grows to infinity, making such a bound impossible.

Comment: Hi, can you explain what bounded by constant means?

Comment: For a positive function $a(n)$ to be bounded by a constant (from some point and onwards) means that there exists a real number $C>0$, such that $a(n) < C$ for all sufficiently large $n$ - i.e. that there is a constant $C>0$ such that all values of $a(n)$ are smaller than $C$ from some $n$.